# Help resolving bug starting X with systemd as a user service

Tags: systemd, xorg

I'm aware there is a question with a similar issue, [like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437809/start-x-server-on-login-with-systemd), however the solutions within there are not specific enough for my situation.

I understand there is a way to start X using `startx` and `xinit` and `logind`, but I wanted to do things this way instead:

For context: I am using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and Systemd

I am trying to use custom user targets and user services to start a bunch of programs upon login from a specific tty, and one of these services is the X server. For the time being, I have the following service file sitting in `~/.config/systemd/user/Xserver.service`, which is meant to start an empty Xorg server on vt7:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the X server
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/X vt07 :0
NoNewPrivileges=false

[Install]
# Irrelevant as of time being, just some custom targets I plan on isolating later.
```

When attempting to start this service,(`systemctl --user start Xserver.service`) however, it fails with exit code 1, and hen reading the Xorg logs I find they say that "switching VT failed".

I understand X at that point is suppposed to be running with root privileges (due to setuid), and is already connected to /dev/tty7, so how is this happening?

What could I do to make it work?

PS: (The reasoning behind systemd allocating ttys dynamically doesn't apply here since I'll have already logged in to the tty by the time this service is started)

Comment: Who owns /dev/tty7? You can check with `ls -l /dev/tty7` if you user doesn't have access to it, I don't believe X will start. If you want to confirm this try hack: `chmod 666 /dev/tty7` and try running your service.

Comment: It's root, as it should, and X is running as root too.

Comment: What do you mean "X is running as root"? I thought you were failing to start X as your user? So how can X already be running? Are you trying to run multiple X servers?